Could anyone translate these characters for me on what I think is a Ming Taoist figure
Good afternoon,
Could anyone translate these characters for me on what I think is a Ming Taoist figure;
Thankyou.

崇禎十六年四月吉日造 - Made on an auspicious day in April of the 16th year of the Chongzhen Era
Chongzhen Era (5-Feb-1628 — 25-Apr-1644）
This thing was made on April 1643

Thankyou very much, ver helpful.

"This thing was made on April 1643." This is true only if the item is not fake. Judging from the lousy characters, I think this is fake.

This item was made on an auspicious day in April of the 16th year of the Chongzhen reign, which means it was manufactured during the reign of the last emperor of the Ming dynasty in China. During the Ming dynasty, craftsmen would inscribe their names and the production dates on the items they made, allowing for tracing of the quality and origin of the products to specific times and individuals. For example, you can see similar inscriptions on the bricks of the Ming city wall in Nanjing, China. Note that the month of April referred to here is based on the Chinese lunar calendar, which could correspond to March in the Gregorian calendar. Similar examples can be seen in the following photographs.

